# Robot Framework Getting Keyword failure reason

Tags: robotframework

Trying to implement a listener interface for robot framework in order to collect information about keyword executions like time taken for execution, Pass/Fail status, failure message in case if status is fail. Sample code is given below

```
import os.path
import tempfile

class PythonListener:
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'GLOBAL'

    def __init__(self, filename='listen.txt'):
        outpath = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), filename)
        self.outfile = open(outpath, 'w')

    def end_keyword(self, name, attrs):
       self.outfile.write(name + "\n")
       self.outfile.write(str(attrs) + "\n")

    def close(self):
       self.outfile.close()
```

All the information apart from keyword failure message is available in the attributes which is passed to end_test method from robot framework.

Documentation can be found here. https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/doc/userguide/src/ExtendingRobotFramework/ListenerInterface.rst#id36

The failure message is available in the attributes for end_test() method. But this will not have information if a keyword is run using RunKeywordAndIgnoreError.

I could see that there is a special variable ${KEYWORD MESSAGE} in robot framework, which contains the possible error message of the current keyword Is it possible to access this variable in the listener class.?
https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/doc/userguide/src/CreatingTestData/Variables.rst#automatic-variables

Are there any other ways to collect the failure message information at the end of every keyword?

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting approach, indeed, `end_test` will ensure an `attributes.message` field containing the failure. (so it goes for `end_suite` if it fails during the suite setup/teardown)

With `end_keyword` you don't have such message, but at least you can filter for the FAIL `status` and detect which one failed. Then the message returned by `Run Keyword And Ignore Error` has to be logged explicitly by you so you can capture such triggering logs with the `log_message` hook. Otherwise nobody is aware of the message of the exception handled by the wrapper keyword which returns a tuple of (status, message).

There's also the `message` hook but couldn't manage to get it called from a normal breaking robot:

> Called when the framework itself writes a syslog message.
> message is a dictionary with the same contents as with log_message method.

Side note: To not expose these hooks as keywords, you can precede the method names with `_`. Examples:

- `def _end_test(self, name, attributes): ...`
- `def _log_message(self, message): ...`